# wordpress plugins multiple user types registration with multple subscriptions for each type of user

Tags: wordpress, membership, user-registration

I have to build a wordpress site that allows register different types of users and let them subscribe to one or more services (or memberships, not sure the wordpress naming convention.

After lot of searching I am confused with most of the wp plugins around.

Which plugin (or plugins, paid or free) should I use to archieve the following behavior:

The system should allow to register, for instance, professional, senior hobbyist, amateur hobbyist and regular user.

- profesional users should be able to subscribe to any(or both) of service1, service2.
- senior users should be able to subscribe to any(or both) of service3, service4
- amateur users should be able to subscribe to any(or both) of service5, service6
- regular users should be able to subscribe to any(or both) of service7, service8

I want to use this setup as starting point for some other projects.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
Your requirement you may want to consider a combination of plugins.
    You can use these combinations  of plugins :
        1. User Role Editor + MemberPress: Create roles using User Role Editor and then set up corresponding memberships in MemberPress.
        2. Members + WooCommerce Subscriptions: Use Members for roles and WooCommerce Subscriptions for managing services.

Implementation Steps
    Install a User Role Management plugin and create your roles.
    Install a Subscription/Membership Management plugin and create services.
    Link roles to services, either manually in the plugin settings or via custom code.
```

Comment: Thanks Jenny for your fast reply. 

I forgot to clarify the subscriptions are paid (some of them with trials periods). 
Also forgot to mention I need to easily allow/deny pages (and/or posts) to some specific roles. 

AFAIU, some of the role/memebers plugins do not _show_ the menu entries, but do not _restrict_ the access if the user puts the url in the navbar.

Do you know if your suggestions (1 or 2) do archieve those requirements?
Thanks again